# BufferedReader returning null in Android application but not in Java application

Tags: java, android, null, bufferedreader

I've written a application in Java which I am trying to port to Android now, but for some reason when using the readLine() method from the BufferedReader it is returning null.  I have tested the code in Java and it works fine no problem.  The file I am reading from is a plain text file which I have put in with the rest of my java files. My code simple takes in user input for a login and upon clicking the login button checks the details by reading in the text file with the profiles in. Below is a simplication of my code:

OnClickListener in main activity:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText textUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textUsername);
            EditText textPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textPassword);

            // Collect the login details entered by the user
            String username = textUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = textPassword.getText().toString();

            // Check if login details are correct
            LoginModel login = new LoginModel();
            Correct = login.isCorrect(username, password); // LINE COMMENTED
            // OUT SO THAT DETAILS DON'T NEED TO BE ENTERED

            //              Correct = true; // used to bypass login for now
            if (Correct) { // if details are correct then start main program
                Intent intent = new Intent (LoginView.this, MenuListView.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else System.out.println("Login is incorrect...");

        }
    });
}
```

The LoginModel.java class:

```
public LoginModel() {
    file = new File("Profiles");
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Login Constructor successful!");
}

// Checks whether the inputted details are correct
public static boolean isCorrect(String u, String p) {
    System.out.println(p);
    boolean check = false;
    String line = null;
    try {
        do {
            line = br.readLine();   // This line is returning null
            // System.out.println("Checking profile : " + line);
            String[] info = line.split("\t");
            // nested if-statement to improve efficiency over &&
            if (info[0].equals(u)) {
                System.out.println("username found!");
                if (info[1].equals(p)) {
                    System.out.println("password correct!");
                    check = true;
                } else
                    System.out.println("password incorrect!");
            } else
                System.out.println("username not found!");
        } while (line != null && check == false);
    return check;
```

It is the br.readLine() which is returning null for some reason.  I've looked it up and bufferedreader seems fully supported.

Edit: Ok, I've found out that it's not actually finding the file but was probably trying to execute the isCorrect() method because it was static.  I've removed the method and br declaration static tags now, and moved the profiles text file to the folder with all my java files in but it still can't find it.  How should I reference the position?  What is the default position for android to look for the file if I simply reference it by name?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is the actual cause of the NPE but it is definetly a bug:

You are initializing `br` in your constructor, but you use it in `isCorrect()` which is static! It does not require an enclosing class of `LoginModel` in oreder to be invoked, so the c'tor might not be called at all before using `br`.

You should initialize `br` when declaring it, or in a static scope, so it will be initialized when the class loads.

**EDIT:** Note that it also indicates that `br` is declared static - so all instances of `LogicModel` actually use the same object of `br`!

The reason why `br.readLine()` is returning null - might be you already exhausted the file in other calls to `isCorrect()`, or other methods which use `br`, but it will be impossible to know it for certain without more code.

Comment: that's a good point - I've just started Java and I had got into a bad habit of declaring a lot of methods as static because it seems to help me avoid lots of scope problems, but obviously there are lots of pitfalls I am now aware of!  I've removed the static modifier, and it hasn't removed the error.  If I am reading from a text file, where should I place it in my Android project?

Comment: Depends, if you need the actual file names for some reason, use assets this is in a seperate folder: [project]/assets. Otherwise you can use raw resources, for which there is the [project]/res/raw folder. You can get a stream using Resources.openRawResource (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int)) or (when using assets) using the assets manager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).

Comment: @user1058210: read my edit regarding why br might have returned null.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the FileNotFoundException wasn't caught? This would mean that Android couldn't find the file and therefore couldn't create the BufferedReader, thereby leaving it null. Search in logcat for a FileNotFoundException (usually in orange) by your process or debug using a breakpoint.

Edit:
When using files in android one usually places them in the res/raw folder. This is because android doesn't have a main starting point for files. In fact android prefers to restrict access to files (because of logical safety issues).

So what you'd have to do:

1. Place the file in the res/raw folder and rename it to "profiles"
   (Android doesn't allow uppercases in resources)(maybe you have to
   create the folder first).
2. Edit your constructor to receive the
   resources (change it to: "public LoginModel(Resources res)")
3. Edit the initializing accordingly (changing "LoginModel login = new
   LoginModel();" to "LoginModel login = new LoginModel(getResources());")
4. Then change "br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));" to "br =
   new BufferedReader(new
   InputStreamReader(res.openRawResources(R.raw.profiles)));"
5. Remove the line "file = new File("Profiles");"

Comment: Hey you were correct- it's not actually finding the file.  I've placed it in the same location as all my Java files and simply referenced it by its name in the code but it still can't find it.  How would I reference its location?